# About updating data in Autodesk Platform Service (forge)

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are trying to link Autodesk Platform Service with MySQLDB built in AWS environment.
We would like to receive data from a specified table in MySQL and update the data displayed on the UI screen at a specified time.
Currently, the data displayed on the screen switches according to browser updates.
The configuration is built using Node.js in LinuxOS.
Is it possible to update the data automatically without having to refresh the browser?

We are still in the research stage, but our current thinking is that we can achieve this by using cron.
Please let us know if you have the best means to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a general web development question and not a one related to APS  platform (or the Viewer component that's part of the platform). Since the question is not very specific, a general answer would be yes, you can update data on your web application in many different ways without having to reload the page, for example:

- you could use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) in your web application to recurrently call a JavaScript function that would repeatedly fetch new/updated data from a server (which would pull the data from your MySQL database)
- you could open a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) channel to your Node.js server app, and the Node.js app would send new data through the channel at whatever rate you want, also using `setInterval` or similar tools